# access selected item from another from

Tags: c#, forms, list, textbox

I have two forms: one has a listbox with a list<>. I need to access the selected item of this textbox on a second form.

First form(GestaoJogadores_Admin):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class GestaoJogadores_Admin : Form
    {
        private DiagramaEntidadesContainer dbATMT;

        public GestaoJogadores_Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbATMT = new DiagramaEntidadesContainer();
            RefreshListaJogadores();
        }

        private void button_editarGestaoJogadores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditarJogador_Admin EditarJogadorAdmin = new EditarJogador_Admin();

            Player jogadorSelecionado = (Player)lb_Jogadores.SelectedItem;

            DialogResult resultado = EditarJogadorAdmin.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Second form(EditarJogador_Admin)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class EditarJogador_Admin: Form
    {

        private DiagramaEntidadesContainer dbATMT;

        public EditarJogador_Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbATMT = new DiagramaEntidadesContainer();
        }

        private void button_EditarJogadorOk_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                GestaoJogadores_Admin GestaoJogadoresAdmin = new GestaoJogadores_Admin();

                Player jogadorSelecionado = (Player)GestaoJogadoresAdmin.jogadorSelecionado;//this is what I need, but it doenst work. I get an errror:  'GestaoJogadores_Admin' does not contain a definition for 'jogadorSelecionado' and no extension method 'jogadorSelecionado' accepting a first argument of type 'GestaoJogadores_Admin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` 
        }
    }
}
```

I open my second form creating an instance of it on the first one and using ShowDialog. On the second on, I thought that if I did the same and tried to access the "jogadorSelecionado" inside of it, It would work, but It doesnt...

Answer (score 1):

In your first form on the button change

```
Player jogadorSelecionado = (Player)lb_Jogadores.SelectedItem;
```

try

```
EditarJogadorAdmin.passFromFormOne = (Player)lb_Jogadores.SelectedItem;
```

And on your second form add the variable to pass it too.

```
public Player passFromFormOne;
```

then

```
 Player jogadorSelecionado = passFromFormOne;
```

Comment: Ok, it worked but now it doenst..sorry...now Im getting that the value comes null. Player jogadorSelecionado = passFromFormOne; is null...